# No such file or directory when we define the path as '~/path/to/csv' in postgres

Tags: postgresql, tilde-expansion

```
lease=# COPY dhcpd_data (ip_address, start_time, end_time, mac_address, machine_name) FROM '~/outputcsvre.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
ERROR:  could not open file "~/outputcsvre.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
```

if i define the path as `'/home/rihiraj12/outputcsvre.csv'`, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's normal.

You don't really have a directory called `~`. When you execute a command on the command line, the shell will expand `~` to `/home/rihiraj12` before running the program. But here you're not using the shell, so `~` is interpreted literally.

As a workaround you could say

```
COPY dhcpd_data (...) FROM PROGRAM 'cat ~/outputcsvre.csv' ...
```

But note that the `COPY` command is executed by the server, so this will make the server spawn a `cat` command and use the home directory of the PostgreSQL server.

To specify the file from your own point of view, you can (in psql) use the `\copy` meta-command (which has the same syntax as `COPY`):

```
\copy dhcpd_data (...) FROM PROGRAM 'cat ~/outputcsvre.csv' ...
```

This will use your own home directory as `~`.

Comment: is there any other way to define the path rather than defining it as an actual path?

Answer (score 1):

`~` is a shortcut that unix-like shells can expand to be the home directory of your user.
i.e. if you use `~/outputcsvre.csv` , the shell converts this to `/home/rihiraj12/outputcsvre.csv` before doing anything else with it.

Outside a shell, applications rarely implement this expansion - and neither does postgresql, so you have to provide real path to the file.

In the case of the COPY command in postgresql, it is executed by the server - so in this case you will have to provide a filename that the server can resolve and read directly. (i.e. a relative path would be relative to wherever the postgresql server is located - so use an absolute path for the file.)

Comment: is there any other way to define the path rather than defining it as an actual path?

Comment: You either need to provide an absolute path such as `/home/rihiraj12/outputcsvre.csv` or a relative path such as `outputcsvre.csv` or `./outputcsvre.csv` or `../outputcsvre.csv` . Relative means a path relative to the current directory you are in.

Comment: @nos For the `COPY` command it's a path relative to the current working directory of the PostgreSQL server, which is probably the cluster's data directory.

Comment: Albeit I think the COPY postgresql command is executed by the server. So a relative path there would be relative to wherever the postgresql server runs.